# Crystal reports Command for date Range in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am editing an application that is made in Visual Studio 2012. I am trying to create a Crystal Report where the user selects a date range. I added a command for my simple SQL Server Query, which runs fine in the SQL Management Studio.

```
Select customerID, orderID, orderDate
From tblOrders
Where orderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2015 00:00:00', 102) 
                    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2016 11:59:59', 102)
```

I then created the parameters From and To as dates and substituted my dates:

```
Select customerID, orderID, orderDate
From tblOrders
Where orderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '{?From} 00:00:00', 102) 
                        AND     
                        CONVERT(DATETIME, '{?To} 11:59:59', 102)
```

I get the following error using the same dates:

```
Failed to retrieve data from the database.
Details: ADO Error Code 0x80040e14
Source Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server Description: Incorrect syntax near '2015'.
SQL State: 42000
Native Error: 102 [Database Vendor Code 102]
```

I tried the query without the Convert function, but get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct code:

```
'{?From} 00:00:00'
```

it can be:

```
{?From}  & " " & '00:00:00' in formula
```

And i am wondering why you want to do like that a `Parameter` with static `time`?

This is the convertion running as tested.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(datetime, CONVERT(varchar,dt,101) + ' 00:00:00',102), 102)
```

you can change the `dt` to `{?From}` in your crystal report

Comment: Remember date format is a very case sensitive. What i mean is check your date if it has the same format from DB to Parameter.

Comment: This is within the Crystal Reports "Modify Command" window in the Visual Studio Project. Tried it anyways, but get the same error, but "Description Invalid Column name ' '.  SQL State: 42S22. Native Error: 207 [Database Vendor Code 207]"

Comment: I used a static time so it would let me select just the date and bring back all within the date since 00:00:00. I noticed that Crystal Reports' date picker automatically selects the current time.

Comment: the column name is not from your formula i guess it's just in your table itself.. try to check it

Comment: I decided to just compile the code and debug and it was actually working fine.